# Order of the associative array in JavaScript by key and access by index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an associative array like:

```
var arr = {};
arr['alz'] = '15a';
arr['aly'] = '16b';
arr['alx'] = '17a';
arr['alw'] = '09c';
```

I need to find the previous and next key of any selected element. Say, for key 'aly' it will be 'alz' and 'alx'. If possible, I want to access the array by index rather than the key.

Currently, I am doing this using a separate array containing keys, e.g.

```
var arrkeys = ['alz','aly','alx','alw'];
```

Comment: The key _is_ the index. There is no other [semantic] ordering.

Comment: That's not how associative arrays work in JavaScript; they're basically objects and the order of the properties is unknown.

Comment: By using non-numeric text in the key, you've converted it to an object. In other words, there is no "associative array." Associative arrays === objects

Comment: `arr={}` is an object not an array.

Comment: @Nile: Not quite; by using `{}` instead of `[]` it's already not an array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, you're right. I'm considering it a typo, however. Not that it'd matter

Comment: @Nile: I see no reason to assume that it's a typo. More likely it's another instance of the common misconception. :)

Comment: @Nile Numeric keys in Javascript are converted to string in both objects AND arrays. JavaScript has no true array! The `Array` object has the added `length` property which is artificially kept first in the list of keys, and that is pretty much it. The phrase "converted it to an object" makes no sense at all, since you can't have any other kind.

Comment: @ErikE: Semantic ordering is an ordering at an abstract layer that's accessible using the abstract data access functions, as opposed to any physical ordering that might come from physical locations in memory. (e.g below) In this case, i.e. JS objects, there isn't any. I freely admit that it's not a concrete, well-established term for this, but I'm certainly not the first to use it. [Here](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/W/W09/W09-3721.pdf)'s an example.

Comment: (Example: C++ `std::map` has a strict weak ordering on the keys, but since maps are generally implemented as trees you won't find the elements laid out in this order consecutively in memory. The ordering is defined by the _semantics_ of the container, rather than inherent in its physical constructs as it would be for an array.)

Comment: @Light The irony of calling memory "physical"! So *semantic* here is supposed to be contrasted with *physical* or *natural*? To me, *explicit* or *defined* is better, but I don't think an extra word is even required, because only a very computer-illiterate person would imagine that "ordering" had to be somehow physical, and even if under this illusion, it would hardly hurt anything.

Comment: @ErikE: Sure, I could have omitted the word. Stack Exchange engineers may charge me for the storage space it takes up if they wish... and both of us for these long comments discussing it.

Comment: @Light Your long name surely costs them whole cents a day in extra bandwidth...

Comment: @ErikE: Most of it is phased into a parallel dimension to aid that

Comment: @ErikE: My nastiness was phased into a parallel dimension to aid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding some syntactic sugar in the form of an `OrderedObject` object? Then you could do something like this:

```
myObj = new OrderedObject();

myObj.add('alz', '15a');
myObj.add('aly', '16b');
myObj.add('alx', '17a');
myObj.add('alw', '09c');

console.log(myObj.keyAt(2)); // 'alx'
console.log(myObj.valueAt(3)); // '09c'
console.log(myObj.indexOf('aly')); // 1
console.log(myObj.length()) // 4
console.log(myObj.nextKey('aly')); // 'alx'
```

The following code makes this work. See it in action [in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXgG8/3/).

```
function OrderedObject() {
   var index = [];
   this.add = function(key, value) {
      if (!this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         index.push(key);
      }
      this[key] = value;
   };
   this.remove = function(key) {
      if (!this.hasOwnProperty(key)) { return; }
      index.splice(index.indexOf(key), 1);
      delete this[key];
   }
   this.indexOf = function(key) {
      return index.indexOf(key);
   }
   this.keyAt = function(i) {
      return index[i];
   };
   this.length = function() {
      return index.length;
   }
   this.valueAt = function(i) {
      return this[this.keyAt(i)];
   }
   this.previousKey = function(key) {
      return this.keyAt(this.indexOf(key) - 1);
   }
   this.nextKey = function(key) {
      return this.keyAt(this.indexOf(key) + 1);
   }
}
```

I made some decisions that may not work for you. For example, I chose to use an `Object` as the prototype rather than an `Array`, so that you could preserve enumerating your object with `for (key in myObj)`. But it didn't have to be that way. It could have been an `Array`, letting you use the property `.length` instead of the function `.length()` and then offering an `each` function that enumerates the keys, or perhaps an `.object()` function to return the inner object.

This could be a little awkward as you'd have to remember not to add items to the object yourself. That is, if you do `myObj[key] = 'value';` then the `index` will not be updated. I also did not provide any methods for rearranging the order of things or inserting them at a particular position, or deleting by position. If you find my object idea useful, though, I'm sure you can figure out how to add such things.

With the newer versions of EcmaScript you can add true properties and make them non-enumerable. This would allow the new object to more seamlessly and smoothly act like the ideal OrderedObject I am imagining.

Comment: That's more like "semantic sugar", surely? You cannot add syntax to JS.

Comment: Yes you can. Object.fn = function () {} sure changes the syntax of that object. Do [a web search for syntactic sugar](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22syntactic+sugar%22) and see you get 306,000 results while [semantic sugar](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantic+sugar%22) only yields 3,940 results. Or read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Comment: The first sentence in that article is: `In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language`. Syntax is a property of the language, not of a program written within that language. That is to say, as I did before, you cannot add syntax to JS.

Comment: And the reason that "semantic sugar" yields fewer results is that it is barely distinguishable from "using the language". This is also the reason I used it in quotation marks in my initial comment. Any further logically comparison based on comparing number of Google results is hardly proof of anything at all...

Comment: It will fit my purpose well. But I want to know, is it performance wise better to use my approach or this one.

Comment: You just have to test and see.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's simple: *syntactic sugar* doesn't mean adding syntax to the language, it means adding sugar to the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Ordering of the object's properties is *undefined*. You can use this structure...

```
[{ key: 'alz', value: '15a'},
 { key: 'aly', value: '16b'},
 { key: 'alx', value: '17a'}]
```

... though searching for the element with the given key (like 'give me the element which `key` is `'alz'`) is not as straight-forward as with simple object. That's why using it like you did - providing a separate array for ordering of the indexes - is another common approach. You can attach this array to that object, btw:

```
var arr={};
arr['alz']='15a';
arr['aly']='16b';
arr['alx']='17a';
arr['alw']='09c';
arr._keysOrder = ['alz', 'aly', 'alx', 'alw'];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an object, not an array, and it sounds like you don't really want those strings to be keys.

How about a nice array?

```
var ar = [
  { key: 'alz', value: '15a' },
  { key: 'aly', value: '16b' },
  { key: 'alx', value: '17a' },
  { key: 'alw', value: '09c' }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to know the order of everything, and still use the keys *and* values, try this:

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'alz', value: '15a' },
    { key: 'aly', value: '16b' },
    { key: 'alx', value: '17a' },
    { key: 'alw', value: '09c' }
];
```

You can then access them sequentially as follows: `arr[0].key` and `arr[0].value`. Similarly, you can find siblings inside of the loop with the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var previous_key = (i > 0) ? arr[(i - 1)].key : false;
    var next_key = (i < (arr.length - 1)) ? arr[(i + 1)].key : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
function sortObject(obj, order)
{
    var list=[], mapArr = [], sortedObj={};
    for(var x in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) list.push(x);
    for (var i=0, length = list.length; i < length; i++) {
        mapArr.push({ index: i, value: list[i].toLowerCase() });
    }
    mapArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(order && order.toLowerCase()==='desc')
            return a.value < b.value ? 1 : -1;
        else return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
    });
    for(var i=0; i<mapArr.length;i++)
        sortedObj[mapArr[i].value]=obj[mapArr[i].value];
    return sortedObj;
}
// Call the function to sort the arr object
var sortedArr = sortObject(arr); // Ascending order A-Z
var sortedArr = sortObject(arr, 'desc'); // Descending order Z-A
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mujsj/1/).

Remember, this will return a new `object` and original `object` will remain unchanged.